# Corrupted message in Outlook 2007 cannot be opened or deleted

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using Outlook 2007. I received an Outlook invite that was forwarded to me (the forward-er is a Mac user, I'm a Windows user).

The message is apparently corrupted. I cannot open it - when attempting to open it it says "Cannot open this item."

When I try to delete it, it says "Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid."

This is the only message affected - I don't have problems with anything else. **Any ideas on what I can do to remove this corrupted message?**

Comment: Have you checked with MS' KB?: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197036

Comment: I did find that article - it does not seem to apply to my situation as it is specific to tasks. Two of the three resolution methods simply do not apply (actions that can only be taken in task view, or actions related to Exchange 5.0). The other resolution could apply but is undesirable - delete my whole Exchange mailbox and start over. I'm hoping for a less drastic solution :)